# How to correctly draw a flat grid of triangles for terrain direct x 11 C++

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to draw a grid of triangles for the first part of my terrain mapping but there is a slight error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Could someone please point out my error or explain how to correctly construct this grid.

To clarify, look at the right side of the grid, that shouldn't happen.

Vertices:

```
vector<Vertex> Terrain::generateVertices(int width, int height) {
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    Vertex v;
    float du = 1.0f / (width - 1);
    float dv = 1.0f / (height - 1);
    for (int r = 0; r < width; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < height; ++c) {
            v.Pos = XMFLOAT3((float)c, (float)r, 0.0f);
            v.Normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            v.TextureCoordinate = XMFLOAT2(c * du, r * dv);
            vertices.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

Indices:

```
vector<WORD> Terrain::generateIndices(int width, int height) {
    vector<WORD> indices;
    for (int r = 0; r < width; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < height; ++c) {
            indices.push_back(r * height + c);
            indices.push_back(r * height + (c + 1));
            indices.push_back((r + 1)*height + c);

            indices.push_back((r + 1) * height + c);
            indices.push_back((r * height + (c + 1)));
            indices.push_back((r + 1) * height + (c + 1));
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Outcome: [image]

When I draw a small grid, for example, 10x10, it comes out exactly how it should

[image]

When I draw a larger grid, 512x512 to cover my terrain, that's when the issues occur with the indices/vertices

Edit: I believe I have found the problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I can draw a grid up to 256x256, but anything over that will give me these graphical issues.

Comment: How do I construct the grid correctly. If you look on the right side of the grid, there is a bug and it's not drawn correctly. The left of the grid is fine.

Comment: The code provided generates the vertex and index buffers for this grid, then I use them buffers to draw it but there is an error somewhere in the generation which causes the problem in the image.

Comment: I thought so too, but clearly something is going wrong.

Comment: What is the problem in the image?

Comment: @MartinBonner I have updated my original post with what the final product should look like.

Comment: @user: I am clearly being dumb.  How does that differ from your result?  Another graphic with just 18 incorrect triangles might help.

Comment: @MartinBonner That's the issue. I cannot draw a small grid with any problems just to demonstrate what's going on. I am able to draw a 200x200 grid perfectly, no issues. Then I tried with a 300x300 and it messes up. I think I've found the issue. Anything over 256x256 causes the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WORD` is a 16-bit unsigned integer with a maximum value of 65535.  With a 300x300 grid you have 90,000 vertices, so you can't index them all with a `WORD`.

Comment: The clue was that it went wrong as you got larger.  Looking at your values, you were going over 8 bits for the number of a vertices on a side, and over 16 bits for the total count. ... Then I saw WORD.